# Implement google map in android to work on blackberry

Tags: android, google-maps, blackberry

Hi i need to convert android application to blackberry (apk2bar). The problem is that when i am trying to convert i am getting "Failed to deploy" error as my application contains google maps library which is  not supported by blackberry.

Can anyone guide me for implementing google maps which will run on blackberry after its conversion from apk2bar.

Edit :  My application contains GeoPoint class to get current lat long from "com.google.android.maps" this the library which Google maps use but not supporetd on BB. So please guide me for subsistution of GeoPoint class in android application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround this using a web based approach. Please read here:
http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/apisupport_mapping_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create google map in your application through the following"

```
String initial = "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 
    "<html> \r\n" + 
    "<head> \r\n" + 
    " <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /> \r\n" + 
    " <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> \r\n" + 
    " <script src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false\" \r\n" + 
    " type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\r\n" + 
    "</head> \r\n" + 
    "<body>\r\n" + 
    " <div id=\"map\" style=\"width: 360px; height: 390px;\"></div>\r\n" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    " <script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n" + 
    " var locations = ["; 
    String second= " ];\r\n" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    " var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {\r\n" + 
    " zoom: 8,"; 
    String centerPoint =""; 
    String finalpart = " mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP\r\n" + 
    " });\r\n" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    " var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();\r\n" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    " var marker, i;\r\n" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    " for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { \r\n" + 
    " marker = new google.maps.Marker({\r\n" + 
    " position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),\r\n" + 
    " map: map\r\n" + 
    " });\r\n" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    " google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {\r\n" + 
    " return function() {\r\n" + 
    " infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);\r\n" + 
    " infowindow.open(map, marker);\r\n" + 
    " }\r\n" + 
    " })(marker, i));\r\n" + 
    " }\r\n" + 
    " </script>\r\n" + 
    "</body>\r\n" + 
    "</html>";
```

Then inside your constructor do the following:

```
String[] lt={x}; 
                   String[] lon={y};
                   String[] name={"CurrentLocation"};
                StringBuffer html=new StringBuffer(); 
                html.append(initial); 
                for(int i=0 ; i<lt.length; i++){ 
                //LocationObj source = (LocationObj)waypoints.elementAt(i); 
                //String point = "['"+source.getLabel()+"',"+source.getLatitude()+","+ source.getLongitude()+","+i+"],"; 
                String point = "['"+name[i]+"',"+lt[i]+","+ lon[i]+","+i+"],"; 
                //System.out.println("Point is"+point); 
                html.append(point); 
                } 
                html.append(second); 
                centerPoint = " center: new google.maps.LatLng("+lt[0]+","+lon[0]+"),"; 
                html.append(centerPoint); 
                html.append(finalpart); 
                //System.out.println("Plot is"+html.toString()); 
                BrowserFieldConfig _bfConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig(); 
                _bfConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER); 
                _bfConfig.setProperty( BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE ); 
                _bfConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_AGENT, "MyApplication 1.0"); 

                BrowserField myBrowserField = new BrowserField(_bfConfig); 

                myBrowserField.displayContent(html.toString(), "");
```

Add myBrowserField inside a vfm or hfm to display on the screen. x & y are the latitude and longitude values (respectively). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i want code in android not in blackberry. The above code is for bb.

Comment: You wrote in your question: "the problem is that when i am trying to convert i am getting "Failed to deploy" error as my application contains google maps library which is not supported by blackberry." Are you not trying to deploy google maps in BlackBerry? If you want to download google maps in BlackBerry, you need to pass a URL in your code that will prompt the user to conduct the download whenever an application is loaded onto a handset with no google maps installed.

Comment: But the "BrowserFieldConfig" class is for BB how can i use it in android code??? And i facing the problem at the time of installing it on BB after its conversion to .bar file

Comment: I am sorry but I guess there a mix up here. I did propose a BlackBerry solution for Google maps (as I understood your question in that way). By the way, can you actually convert an android app (source code) to BlackBerry?

Comment: There is tool provided by BB to convert apk 2 bar

Comment: I think he might be developing for BB10 using the Android Runtime.